# The extreme-flat theme for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I saw a extreme-flat theme for Ubuntu 14.04 somewhere. Can anybody tell me how can I install this theme?
[image: ubuntu14.04]

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: It's not for real. It's a mockup. See [Ubuntu Flat UI Concept](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Flat-UI-Concept-445281381) by "TTT" (The Techno Toast) at devianArt.

Comment: Oh - well if it's just a mockup, there's not really a good way short of making it by hand.

Comment: A late April fools' day? :)

Comment: Hi @CalebXu, if you can visit [weibo in China](http://weibo.com/1306438921/AFQeH1nTn)

Comment: @sammyg, thanks for your link... I was upgrading Ubuntu with full of hope....

Comment: The same mockup is used at [LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-14-10-will-come-with-important-changes-bringing-convergence-one-step-further/) and at [Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Starts-Talking-About-Convergence-and-Ubuntu-14-10-Features-437648.shtml) and only the latter points out that it's a *Ubuntu concept*. But they fail to give credit to the artist.

Comment: @Marslo Dont' mention it! :) I wish I could have something like that. It really, really looks great! Hehe, but we can always keep dreaming.

Comment: @sammyg IPhone can always lead the fashion.... I DON'T like flat-theme until ISO7.x came... After that, I found I'd like everything flatty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have discussed, the theme you posted is a mockup (concept). If what you want is a flat GTK theme, you might want to check out [Iris](http://thevirtualdragon.deviantart.com/art/Iris-Dark-Gtk-Theme-v1-5-429628194).

[image: a]

> Few ‘third party themes’ seem to integrate as well with Ubuntu’s
>   default desktop as those included with it!
>
> [‘Iris’ Is a Stylish Flat GTK Theme for Linux](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/iris-flat-gtk-theme-for-linux)

Comment: Thanks! I've searched that theme also. But the [dark-theme](http://thevirtualdragon.deviantart.com/art/Iris-Dark-Gtk-Theme-v1-5-429628194) ISN'T too 'dark'. However, let me have a try..

Comment: I don't know how, but it shows `Theme file invalid` after installed the zip by ubuntu tweak... I will try it by manual way.

Comment: By the way, [Flattasic](http://nale12.deviantart.com/art/Flattastic-11-03-2014-424913255) is also looks good. But, I like dark theme...

Comment: Wow that looks awesome. I especially like the icons up the top-right. Will this work with Unity? Sorry if that's a dumb question, I'm kinda new to Ubuntu.